# react native iOS add firebase with pod encounter 404 error

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, cocoapods

I need to add firebase in a react native project

I init pod in iOS project and edit pod like below:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'ProjectName****' do

 pod 'Firebase/Core'

end
```

after that I run pod install, so the result like below:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Firebase (4.13.0)

[!] Error installing Firebase [!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/8y/24chrcxx1jb20tf7knths56c0000gn/T/d20180505-5700-19mr5c1/file.tgz https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/b64ddeea923b5ab5/Firebase-4.13.0.tar.gz --create-dirs --netrc-optional

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0 curl: (22) 
**The requested URL returned error: 404**
```

[image]

I can not find any solution for this problem. please help me

Comment: Can you hit the URL (https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/b64ddeea923b5ab5/Firebase-4.13.0.tar.gz) from the machine you are trying to run this on?

Comment: @wottle Yes, I can.

Comment: Could be a spurious network issue - try again

Comment: Do you have a proxy on the machine you are truing to run this on?

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what's going on there; here are a few suggestions:

1. Run `pod update`
2. Try a higher iOS version, I believe cocoapods 1.4+ only supports iOS 9.3
3. Remove your `Pods` folder and `Podfile.lock` and try `pod install` again

Answer (score 0):

it's error error: 404 , which means that you can't reach to that package.
either change the version of that package .
or use a vpn (may be your ip is blocked from reaching to that package ) .